# structuremap configuration to substitute only 1 dependency

Tags: structuremap

If I have a class with lots of dependencies, e.g:

```
public ClassWithManyDependencies(IDependencyA a, IDependencyB b, 
                                 IDependencyC c, IDependencyD d, 
                                 IDependencyE e, IDependencyF f, 
                                 IDependencyG g, IDependencyH h): IClassWithManyDependencies

{
    // constructor code...
}
```

when I want to inject a different implementation *of just one* of those dependencies (say **IDependencyH**) - and I want dependencies on IDependencyH in other classes to use the default implementation - I am currently doing this:

```
var specialVersionH = new DecoratedDependencyH();

For<IClassWithManyDependencies>().Use(c => new ClassWithManyDependencies(
    c.GetInstance<IDependencyA>(),
    c.GetInstance<IDependencyB>(),
    c.GetInstance<IDependencyC>(),
    c.GetInstance<IDependencyD>(),
    c.GetInstance<IDependencyE>(),
    c.GetInstance<IDependencyF>(),
    c.GetInstance<IDependencyG>(),
    specialVersionH));
```

Is there a more concise way to configure structuremap to use the default versions of each dependency *except* for a specified one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is for 2.6.

```
ForConcreteType<ClassWithManyDependencies>()
  .Configure.Ctor<IDependencyH>()
  .Is<DecoratedDependencyH>();
For<IClassWithManyDependencies>().Use(ctx => ctx.GetInstance<ClassWithManyDependencies>());
```

I ran a "simplified" test, seemed to work.

Comment: That got me 90% there - I specifically need classes dependent on `IClassWithManyDependencies` to use the special config too (not just when I call `GetInstance<ClassWithManyDependencies>()` at "root level").  I've amended your answer with the extra step needed to make this work too.